# How to schedule a function in functions.php to run once a day

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, hook-woocommerce

Quero que esse código rode uma vez ao dia em meu site:

```
    function wp_order_completed() {
    global $wpdb;

    $my_query = "SELECT * FROM 0czr9_wc_order_stats WHERE STATUS='wc-processing'";
    $val123 = $wpdb->get_row($my_query, OBJECT);
    $result2 = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);
    
    foreach ($result2 as $results2) {
        $date1 = $results2->date_paid;
        $order_id = $results2->order_id;

        
        
        $date2 = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        $dteStart = new DateTime($date1);
        $dteEnd   = new DateTime($date2);
        $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
        $Diff = $dteDiff->format("%d");
        $int = (int)$Diff;

        // Instrução de depuração para verificar a diferença calculada
              echo "<script>console.log('Diferença de dias: {$order_id} {$int}')</script>";
              

        if ($int >= 7) {
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
            if (!empty($order)) {
                $order->update_status('completed');
            }
        }
    }
}

// add_action('init', 'wp_order_completed');
```

If I uncomment this add_action('init', 'wp_order_completed') the code runs all the time, and makes my site slow, I wanted to run this code only once a day.

Comment: You can use [wp_schedule_single_event](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_single_event/)

Comment: @Bhautik how can i do this using my own code?

Comment: What have you tried so far for `If the order has the status waiting, and after 3 days,` and `I want the status to change after 15 days to completed`

Comment: @Bhautik Ok. but where does the schedule go in the code?

Comment: check the doc of `wp_schedule_single_event` you will get an idea of how it works.

Comment: I looked and understood how it works, but I am not able to understand the reason for the critical error to disappear, since I will only be scheduling the function with an error...